# how to find the number of value matches with different user ids from the table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to make it so that the script displays the number of matched values with different users.
For example, in table `watched` i have my main user's id(1) and his watched movie titles and also multiple other users' watched movies:

```
+----+----------+---------+
| id | users_id | watched |
+----+----------+---------+
| 1  | 1        | movie1  |
+----+----------+---------+
| 2  | 1        | movie2  |
+----+----------+---------+
| 3  | 1        | movie3  |
+----+----------+---------+
| 4  | 2        | movie2  |
+----+----------+---------+
| 5  | 2        | movie1  |
+----+----------+---------+
| 6  | 3        | movie1  |
+----+----------+---------+
| 7  | 3        | movie5  |
+----+----------+---------+
| 8  | 3        | movie4  |
+----+----------+---------+
```

Expected output:

```
my id = `1`;
matched with id `2` 2 times on titles `movie2`, `movie1`;
matched with id `3` 1 times on titles `movie1`;
```

Or if the main user's id is `3`:

```
my id = `3`;
matched with id `1` 1 times on titles `movie1`;
matched with id `2` 1 times on titles `movie1`;
```

And so on..

I have tried to do something like:

```
<?php
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "root", "movie");

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM profile INNER JOIN users ON profile.users_id = users.id");

$id = $_SESSION['id'];
echo "my id: " . $id;

$movies = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM watched WHERE users_id = '$id'");

$titles = array();
for ($i = 0;$i < $movies->num_rows;$i++)
{
    $result2 = $movies->fetch_assoc();
    $watched = $result2['watched'];
    $find = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM watched WHERE watched = '$watched'");

    for ($l = 0;$l < $find->num_rows;$l++)
    {
        $found = $find->fetch_assoc();
        if ($found['watched'] === $result2['watched'] and $found['users_id'] !== $id)
        {
            $titles[] = $found['watched'];

        }
    }
}

$count_titles = array();
foreach ($titles as $a)
{
    @$count_titles[$a]++;
}
$matches = count($count_titles); //num of matches

for ($i = 0;$i < $query->num_rows;$i++)
{
    $result = $query->fetch_assoc();

?>

<div><?php
echo "matched with id " . $result['id'] . " ";

echo $matches . " times";

foreach (array_keys($count_titles) as $key)
{
    echo " on titles " . $key;
}

?></div> 


<?php
} ?>
```

But it displays only the total number of matches all over the table, not for each user individually. How do I make it work like described above?

three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE watched (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `users_id` INTEGER,
  `watched` VARCHAR(6)
);

INSERT INTO watched
  (`id`, `users_id`, `watched`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'movie1'),
  ('2', '1', 'movie2'),
  ('3', '1', 'movie3'),
  ('4', '2', 'movie2'),
  ('5', '2', 'movie1'),
  ('6', '3', 'movie1'),
  ('7', '3', 'movie5'),
  ('8', '3', 'movie4');

  CREATE TABLE users (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(355),
  `email` VARCHAR(355)
);

INSERT INTO users
  (`id`, `name`, `email`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'name1', 'email1@mail.com'),
  ('2', 'name2', 'email2@mail.com'),
  ('3', 'name3', 'email3@mail.com');

  CREATE TABLE profile (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `users_id` INTEGER,
  `about` VARCHAR(355)
);

INSERT INTO profile
  (`id`, `users_id`, `about`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'something about me'),
  ('2', '2', 'something about me'),
  ('3', '3', 'something about me');
```

Comment: It probably displays multiple rows for each user, which is expected, it's not going to somehow magically group them (typically one does this in PHP).  The best you could do in SQL is probably `GROUP_CONCANT` and then group on user id.

Comment: Where exactly should I do it? Could you please maybe show me.?

Comment: A lot of this makes no sense, for example `SELECT * FROM watched WHERE users_id = '$id'` Then you take `watched` fields value from that and do this with it `SELECT * FROM watched WHERE watched = '$watched'`  So you already have what this returns in `$watched ~ $result2;`

Comment: yeah... I'm sorry, I know. I am new to mysql/php. do you have a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the raw data that you want:

```
SELECT w1.users_id AS user1, w2.users_id AS user2, GROUP_CONCAT(w2.watched ORDER BY w2.watched) AS movies
FROM watched w1
JOIN watched w2 ON w2.watched = w1.watched AND w2.users_id != w1.users_id
GROUP BY user1, user2
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
user1   user2   movies
1       2       movie1,movie2
1       3       movie1
2       1       movie1,movie2
2       3       movie1
3       1       movie1
3       2       movie1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fU9ADMjY9mQ12rB1wVwU7F/4)

You can refine the query as necessary (e.g. add `WHERE w1.users_id = 1` to select only matches with user 1, or `JOIN` to your `users` and `profile` tables (once for each user id) to get user names etc.)

To get the output you desire you don't really need any more tables, you can just use something like:

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
echo "my id: $id\n";
$movies = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT w1.users_id AS user1, 
                                         w2.users_id AS user2, 
                                         COUNT(w2.watched) AS num_movies, 
                                         GROUP_CONCAT(w2.watched ORDER BY w2.watched) AS movies
                                  FROM watched w1
                                  JOIN watched w2 ON w2.watched = w1.watched AND w2.users_id != w1.users_id
                                  WHERE w1.users_id = $id
                                  GROUP BY user1, user2");
while ($row = $movies->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "matched with id {$row['user2']} {$row['num_movies']} times on titles {$row['movies']}\n";
}
```

Comment: I was thinking I could combine all the tables ( all 3 ) and do just one SQL for the whole thing...  but alas I don't know what the other two tables are `SELECT
         {other fields here}
         GROUP_CONCAT(w.watched) as watched
     FROM
         profile AS p
     JOIN
        users AS u ON p.users_id = u.id
     LEFT JOIN
        watched AS w ON w.users_id = u.id
     WHERE
         u.id = ?
     GROUP BY w.users_id`  Thats as far as I got.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix totally agree (that's what my last comment in the answer was about) but I didn't think there was enough data in the question to be able to write that query

Comment: I'm too lazy to figure more out .... lol ... I did find out the hard way there is a limit on how long you can go with Group Concat ...  It's pretty big though.  I was using it for a materialized path, and it was truncating stuff (mysteriously)  Basically we had some nested set hierarchy data but in some cases we just wanted the full path to that node from the root, so I used that to shortcut having to calculate it all the time.

Comment: hi!! thanks for the answer! I read the comments and added the table data in the question. though there's nothing that much important to it. Anyways, could you please check out? @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: @valeria see my edit, you don't really need the extra tables to get the output you want

Comment: hi again!! I have been trying to join the other two tables users and profile, but with no success so far. i wrote `LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id=w2.users_id
                                  LEFT JOIN profile AS p ON p.users_id=u.id` as you said, after the line `WHERE w1.users_id = $id`. does it not work because there's something wrong with the query or the order of the lines?

Comment: @valeria take a look at this, I started playing with `JOIN`ing the `users` table. If it's not enough, then I think you should ask a new question. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fU9ADMjY9mQ12rB1wVwU7F/5